# How can I get the median in a csv using pandas?

Tags: pandas, median, keyerror

So I'm just learning the pandas library, and I think this this shouldn't be that difficult, and I don't know why I'm being thrown a Key Error. I may be doing this wrong, since I am a beginner with python. But I was wondering why I can't find the median of a csv with the following code? I'm using repl.it to run this code as well.

```
import pandas 
census  = pandas.read_csv("census(1).csv")
median = census[0].median()
print(median)
```

If you need to I can post the csv if that may help debug this. I am trying to get the median of the first column, I would call it by name, but the column doesn't have a header. I looked in my book and this how they instruct it be coded if the column doesn't have header. The Key Error thrown was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/.site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2525, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(key)
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
median = census[0].median()
File "/tmp/.site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2139, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)
File "/tmp/.site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2146, in _getitem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)
File "/tmp/.site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1842, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
File "/tmp/.site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3843, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
File "/tmp/.site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2527, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0
```

First two lines of the csv:

```
  39     State-gov  77516    Bachelors  13   Never-married   Adm-clerical    Not-in-family   White   Male   2174    0   40   United-States   <=50K
  50     Self-emp-not-inc   83311    Bachelors  13   Married-civ-spouse  Exec-managerial     Husband     White   Male   0   0   13   United-States   <=50K
```

Comment: obviously there is no column named `0`. Better provide us with 2 lines of the csv and show the dataframe `census` after you read it in.

Comment: Here is the first two lines of the csv                                                                                                                                                                       39  State-gov 77516  Bachelors 13  Never-married  Adm-clerical  Not-in-family  White  Male 2174 0 40  United-States  <=50K
50  Self-emp-not-inc 83311  Bachelors 13  Married-civ-spouse  Exec-managerial  Husband  White  Male 0 0 13  United-States  <=50K

Comment: Unless my answer was what you needed, you'll need to include the column names as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is looking for a column, whereas `census[0]` will return the first row. If you know you want the first column, you can tell it you want that by using `df.columns[0]`.

So that would be `census[census.columns[0]].median()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel a little dumb. Thanks for explaining that in detail!

Comment: No problem! It took me a while to figure it out when I started using pandas.